# Arrays and methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Alright so this question is driving me insane.

How would I use an array as a parameter in a method

Say I have SetTemperature as a method, how would I copy that to say the temperature array?

Also how would I get the highest int/value etc in my array using a method?

Comment: I'll be the first to say it: What have you tried?

Comment: let me be the first to down vote this non-question

Comment: @Bohemian, this is a legitimate question, the OP just hasn't shown their effort.

Comment: No need to apologize... Just show us what you've tried and we'll be happy to help.  Otherwise, people aren't going to be anxious to do your homework for you.

Comment: Hi John, welcome to StackOverflow. Novice questions are OK here, as long as some steps are taken. Please take the time to put some example code in your post. As other posters have noted, it's important to show that you are not trying to get other people to code for you. A detailed post explaining your problem, the solutions you have tried and giving some example code will go a long way to convince people of your good intentions. I don't know Java, but if I can see the syntax I might be able to work something out.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an array as a parameter precisely the same way as any other variable; instead of:

```
public void someMethod(int foo) {
    //important code
}

int foobar = 1;
someMethod(foobar);
```

You would say,

```
public void someMethod(int[] foo) {
    //important code
}

int foobar = {1, 3, 2};
someMethod(foobar);
```

As for finding the highest int value in the array, I invite you to use a combination of Google and your own problem-solving-skills to attempt to figure that out on your own- and if you're still having trouble, that's another topic for another question.

Comment: +1 for "_I invite you to use a combination of Google and your own problem-solving skills_"!

Comment: I think I simply thought myself in circles. Makes a lot more sense now than when I posted this.